# How to know when/what exceptions are thrown by System.Data.Sqlite objects?

Tags: .net, sqlite, exception, system.data.sqlite

I'm having trouble finding out, for the [Sqlite.Net data provider (System.Data.Sqlite.dll)](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) (new development has forked [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/)), what exceptions are thrown by the various classes and their methods. I know there are SqliteExceptions that can be thrown, but when?

I have ensured I have the accompanying System.Data.Sqlite.xml documentation file, but it doesn't appear to list what exceptions are thrown by each method.

I don't want to wrap unnecessary code into try/catch blocks (or blindly catch a generic Exception everywhere).

I know that SqliteConnection is derived from [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and SqliteCommand is derived from [DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), so if necessary I guess I can look at the documentation there. However, none of the base classes will list SqliteException, so when will those type of exceptions be thrown?

PS - I'm using version 1.0.64 (from 2009... can't upgrade at this time).

---

UPDATE:

Due to the lack of responses, is there anyone out there that uses System.Data.Sqlite.dll? If so, what approach do you take to handle exceptions that may be thrown from the objects available in the library? Is there some standard way to deal with these exceptions since it seems there is no documentation on the exceptions that are thrown and by which classes?

---

UPDATE 2:

I did manage to find the SQLite.NET documentation found under c:\program files\SQLite.NET\Doc\ (seems kind of obvious). Great documentation so far, however it doesn't tell you what exceptions are thrown. The best I can do so far is to look at the base classes that are inherited or interfaces that are implemented and see what exceptions are thrown. This still doesn't help in knowing when an SqliteException object is thrown though.

---

UPDATE 3:

After getting a hold of the source code, it appears that none of the classes themselves contain any `/// <exception cref="ExceptionType">Something went wrong!</exception>` xml comments. This explains why neither the SQLite.NET help file or Visual Studio Intellisense is listing any exceptions that may be thrown. I've created a [ticket](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/1c2dd41f57e0a1019eaf450623b36d8ea565fa5c) requesting the xml comments to include the exceptions, offering to add them myself if it is too low on their priority list. I'll keep this question updated with any new developments for anyone who might be interested.

Comment: Yay, the tumbleweed badge...*cries*

Comment: They've got some additional questions for you in your ticket in regards to working on the xml exception reporting for this as well as an update to the ticket status here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=1c2dd41f57

Comment: @Mat Nadrofsky: Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Mat Nadrofsky: Looks like they're not actually asking me questions... they are rhetorical. They're basically not sure how detailed to get with exceptions (do you document all exceptions, including ones that could be thrown by the .Net framework, do you include ones that bubble and and are not handled in the current method, do you include only ones you throw explicitly), so are keeping it as a low priority. This has always been an area that I have wondered on the proper approach as well.

Comment: This is quite frustrating. It is a shame that there is not a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

you could use the "brute" way searching into code or by reflector for Exception.

Es:
reflector --> analyze "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException" --> Instantiated By

```
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_Blob(SQLiteStatement, Int32, Byte[]) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_DateTime(SQLiteStatement, Int32, DateTime) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_Double(SQLiteStatement, Int32, Double) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_Int32(SQLiteStatement, Int32, Int32) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_Int64(SQLiteStatement, Int32, Int64) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_Null(SQLiteStatement, Int32) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Bind_Text(SQLiteStatement, Int32, String) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.ChangePassword(Byte[]) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.ColumnMetaData(String, String, String, String&, String&, Boolean&, Boolean&, Boolean&) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.CreateCollation(String, SQLiteCollation, SQLiteCollation) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.CreateFunction(String, Int32, Boolean, SQLiteCallback, SQLiteCallback, SQLiteFinalCallback) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.GetIndexColumnExtendedInfo(String, String, String, Int32&, Int32&, String&) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum, Int32, Boolean) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection, String, SQLiteStatement, UInt32, String&) : SQLiteStatement
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement) : Int32
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.SetPassword(Byte[]) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.SetTimeout(Int32) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement) : Boolean
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3_UTF16.Bind_Text(SQLiteStatement, Int32, String) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3_UTF16.Open(String, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum, Int32, Boolean) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteBase.CloseConnection(SQLiteConnectionHandle) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteBase.FinalizeStatement(SQLiteStatementHandle) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteBase.ResetConnection(SQLiteConnectionHandle) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.CheckClosed() : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteStatement.BindParameter(Int32, SQLiteParameter) : Void
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.IsValid(Boolean) : Boolean
```

Comment: So each method listed above instantiates (and likely throws) an instance of SQLiteException?

Comment: yes, I looked for exception in sqllite assembly and I found only this class that has 'exception' in its name. Then I tried on what class was instantiated. Hope this helps. sorry for my late reply. I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but this tip will come in handy. Especially since it looks like they are not planning to document the exceptions any time soon. Thanks!

Comment: with reflector you can  see the code which throw those exception

Comment: I really should get more familiar with reflector.